# Hide ContactForm7 fields with CSS

Tags: wordpress

Currently I'm working on a site that sends out quotations to clients  through the auto-reply function from ContactForm7.

I am using the 'Calculate Contact Form' plug-in to calculate a sum.

What happens now is that the outcome of this sum is shown in the form.  However, the outcome of a sum shouldn't be shown in the form itself, rather only in the auto-respond e-mail.

I tried some plug-ins that hide a field on the front-end, but these hidden tags also make it that the [calculator-598] (which is the sum) tag is not shown correctly in the auto-respond any longer.

So, I am looking to hide one field on the front-end only through CSS so that the [calculator-598] tag in the auto-respond message stays intact. But I have no clue how to do so.

Can anyone explain me how to do achieve this?

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap calculator-598"><input type="text" name="calculator-598" value="0" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-calculator wpcf7-validates-as-calculator occf7cal-total" readonly="readonly" data-formulas="textarea-x * 40"></span>
```

Comment: <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap calculator-598"><input type="text" name="calculator-598" value="0" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-calculator wpcf7-validates-as-calculator occf7cal-total" readonly="readonly" data-formulas="textarea-aantal-letters * 40"></span>

Answer (score 1):

```
span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.calculator-598 {
    display: none;
}
input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-calculator.wpcf7-validates-as-calculator.occf7cal-total {
    display: none;
}
```